# How to change view height based on device? (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm working on modifying this app, and it has a view that fills the screen. Unfortunately, this is all set statically in the interface builder.

Is there a button somewhere on XCode (I'm new to XCode) that will tell it to automatically fill the device screen?

If not, how can I change the height programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Do some searching on autolayout.

Comment: Looking into it now, thanks.

Comment: If the app is not currently using auto layout, the simplest answer to your first question is to use springs/struts on a view to have it resize based on the size of the screen. Auto layout does this as well, but if the app is not already using auto layout, it may cause more headaches than it is worth to make just this simple change.

Comment: Well it's a very small app. I don't think putting it on auto-layout will cause any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Then you can set the view accordingly like so:

```
self.view.frame = screenBounds;
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Waiting on feedback from iPhone 5 user.

Answer (score 1):

Set your controller's frame as you want it to be in Interface Builder. For example, if you're working on iPad simulator and want the view to be full screen, set x and y to 0 and set the width and height to 768 and 1024 on portrait or 1024 and 768 if you have selected landscape. I also suggest working with springs and struts which is easier to start with. For that you need to select your controller, and go to `File Inspector` tab on right and uncheck `Use AutoLayout`

[image]

No go to `springs and struts` tab, and make sure that you have set it to expand in both width and height while maintaining its distance from left, top, right, and bottom.

[image]

That would make your view resize itself depending on the device size.

Comment: I can't seem to enable the inner arrow things at 'Autosizing'. What exactly do those do, anyway?

Comment: That's why I told you to disable the 'Autoresizing'. That's gonna be more problem to use and most developers are still using this technique. You have to disable 'Autoresizing' as shown in first image. Then you will be able to set it like this.

Comment: I've done that and I see the option for autosizing, but clicking the inner arrows does nothing.

Comment: You're using storyboard or xib? If you're using storyboard and it is your root view, that's correct, you can't set the inner arrows. However, as long as you have the other surroundings, your view will change size by device screen size. Just make sure to also handle your inner views springs and struts for them in a correct way.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not sure. The file is certainly an xib file. I'm very new to xcode. Our iOS dev quit the other day and so I'm kind of winging it to help fill his place a bit.

Comment: So there are two ways to do it. One is by code which @JustAnotherCoder mentioned. One other way is in IB which can be done through "Autoresize" for iOS6 and after or springs and struts, mentioned above.